# How to create VIEW in MS Access Database using Delphi Application without installing MSAccess on PC?

Tags: database, delphi, ms-access, view

I want to create VIEW definitions on MS Access. I have used following `CREATE VIEW` Statement:

```
SELECT 
   MFP.FollowUpPlan_Id, 
   MFP.FollowUpPlan_Name AS PlanName, 
   DFP.Sequence_No AS SequenceNo, 
   MFS.FollowUpSchedule_Name AS ScheduleName    
FROM 
   MAS_FollowUp_Plan AS MFP, 
   DET_FollowUp_Plan AS DFP, 
   MAS_FollowUp_Schedule AS MFS
WHERE 
   (((MFP.FollowUpPlan_Id)=DFP.FollowUpPlan_Id) AND
   ((DFP.FollowUpSchedule_Id)=MFS.FollowUpSchedule_Id)) AND
   MFP.is_Deleted = FALSE AND
   DFP.is_Deleted = false     
ORDER BY 
   MFP.FollowUpPlan_Id, DFP.Sequence_No;
```

but it throw an error:

```
Only Simple Select Queries are allowed in view.
```

Please Help, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try to remove the `ORDER BY` part from your query and use it when you select from that view like for instance `SELECT * FROM YourView ORDER BY FollowUpPlan_Id, SequenceNo`.

Comment: Would a query rather than a view suit? It will allow a lot more in the way of sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare variable olevarCatalog ,cmd as OleVariant in Delphi, Uses ComObj

```
olevarCatalog := CreateOleObject('ADOX.Catalog');
olevarCatalog.create(YourConnectionString); //This Will create MDB file.
// Using ADO Query(CREATE TABLE TABLEName....) add the required Tables.

// To Insert View Definition on MDB file.
cmd := CreateOleObject('ADODB.Command');
cmd.CommandType := cmdText;
cmd.CommandText := 'ANY Kind of SELECT Query(JOIN, OrderBy is also allowed)';
olevarCatalog.Views.Append('Name of View',cmd);
cmd := null;
```

This is a best way to Create MS ACCESS File(.MDB) and VIEWs using Delphi.

Answer (score 7):

The issue here, as Jeroen explained, is a limitation of Access' `CREATE VIEW` statement.  For this case, you can use `CREATE PROCEDURE` instead.  It will create a new member of the db's `QueryDefs` collection --- so from the Access user interface will appear as a new named query.

The following statement worked for me using ADO from VBScript.  From previous Delphi questions on here, my understanding is that Delphi can also use ADO, so I believe this should work for you, too.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ViewSubstitute AS
SELECT
    MFP.FollowUpPlan_Id,
    MFP.FollowUpPlan_Name AS PlanName,
    DFP.Sequence_No AS SequenceNo,
    MFS.FollowUpSchedule_Name AS ScheduleName
FROM
    (MAS_FollowUp_Plan AS MFP
    INNER JOIN DET_FollowUp_Plan AS DFP
    ON MFP.FollowUpPlan_Id = DFP.FollowUpPlan_Id)
    INNER JOIN MAS_FollowUp_Schedule AS MFS
    ON DFP.FollowUpSchedule_Id = MFS.FollowUpSchedule_Id
WHERE
    MFP.is_Deleted=False AND DFP.is_Deleted=False
ORDER BY
    MFP.FollowUpPlan_Id,
    DFP.Sequence_No;
```

Comment: +!; Thanks for teaching me that Access has "create procedure" which is very much like "create view" but without some of the limitations.

Answer (score 4):

[You cannot mix `ORDER BY` with `JOIN` when creating views in Access](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robert_mcmurray/archive/2009/09/25/creating-a-microsoft-access-provider-for-iis-database-manager.aspx). It will get you the error ["`Only simple SELECT queries are allowed in VIEWS.`"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Only%20Simple%20Select%20Queries%20are%20allowed%20in%20views%22) (note the plural VIEWS)

Having multiple tables in the `FROM` is a kind of to `JOIN`.

- either remove the `ORDER BY`,
- or have only one table in the `FROM` and no `JOIN`s.

I remember from the past (when I did more Access stuff than now) seeing this for a large query with a single table select with an `ORDER BY` as well.

[The consensus is that you should not have `ORDER BY` in views anyway](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/08/23/sql-server-order-by-does-not-work-limitation-of-the-views-part-1/), so that is your best thing to do.

[Another reason that you can get the same error message](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/HV080760732.aspx) is if you add parameters or sub selects. Access does not like those in views either, but that is not the case in your view.